# Vb.Net Windows Application To C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Porting VB.NET Winforms Application to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335270/porting-vb-net-winforms-application-to-c-sharp)

Is there any way to convert a vb.net winforms application into c# ? In terms of both code and .vb (forms) files.

Comment: I think this link has all the answers [as stated below too] - http://stackoverflow.com/q/756590/763026. This question is a duplicate and should be closed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/) is an IDE that can convert entire **Visual Studio** projects from VB.NET to C# (and the other way around).

Last time I used it, it had some small limitations (such as optional parameters in VB.NET), but  did a great job overall.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

This one works, but is not perfect of course. You should review the converted files and correct eventual mistakes by hand.